# How to multiply array by an integer without numpy

Tags: python

```
def multArray(A, k):
    A = [i * k for i in A]
    return A
# tests
tests = (([5,12,31,7,25],10), 
     ([-5,12,-31,7,25],10),
     ([-5,12,-31,7,25],-1),
     ([-5,12,-31,7,25],0),
     ([],10),
     ([],-1))

# should print: [50,120,310,70,250],[-50,120,-310,70,250],[5,-12,31,-7,-25],[0,0,0,0,0],[],[]
for (A,k) in tests: 
    multArray(A, k)
    print(A)
```

This is the solution I see on here from other questions but I can't seem to get it to work. Needs to be done without maps or numpty.

Comment: `[i * k for i in A]` should work

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: make sure to correct your indentation

Comment: indentation on my actual code is okay

Comment: `multArray` works, but you forget to assign to output of you function in your `for` loop. So you print the original A, instead of the output from `multArray`. `A = multArray(A, k)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is creating a new list with the updated values, however, the test prints the original list. To multiple the original list by a factor you need to update the values in the original list, something like this:

```
def multArray(A, k):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        A[i] *= k

# tests
tests = (([5,12,31,7,25],10), 
     ([-5,12,-31,7,25],10),
     ([-5,12,-31,7,25],-1),
     ([-5,12,-31,7,25],0),
     ([],10),
     ([],-1))

for (A,k) in tests: 
    multArray(A, k)
    print(A)
```

#### Creating new list vs. updating existing list

It must be noted that it is much quicker to create a new list in a case like this. If we look at the performance of creating a new list versus updating the existing list:

```
python -m timeit -s "a = [i for i in range(100)]" "b = [i * 7 for i in a]"
```

executes in:

```
50000 loops, best of 5: 8.54 usec per loop
```

whereas:

```
python -m timeit -s "a = [i for i in range(100)]" "for i in range(len(a)): a[i] *= 7"
```

executes in:

```
5000 loops, best of 5: 40.6 usec per loop
```

So it is roughly x5 faster to create a new list. There is an argument to say updating the existing list is more memory efficient, but certainly not for these types of examples.

#### Relative performance of numpy array

It should also be noted that multiplying all the elements in a numpy array by a particular value is much faster than either method using lists.

```
python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; a = np.array([i for i in range(100)])" "a = a * 7"
```

executes in:

```
500000 loops, best of 5: 839 nsec per loop
```

This is because the memory allocated in numpy arrays is contiguous in memory so operations benefit from a wide range processor level caching effects.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot edit the code below my function

Comment: @yeppidyyepster65 what do you mean with I cannot edit that code?

Comment: it is a question in one of my assignments, I can only edit the function